# Tombstone in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a Cassandra table with TTL of 60 seconds, I have few questions in this,

1) I am getting the following warning

```
Read 76 live rows and 1324 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM xx.yy WHERE token(y) >= token(fc872571-1253-45a1-ada3-d6f5a96668e8) LIMIT 100 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
```

What does this mean?

2) As per my study, Tombstone is a flag in case of TTL (will be deleted after gc_grace_seconds) 
   i) so till 10 days does it mean that it won't be deleted ?
   ii) What will be the consequence of it waiting for 10 days?
   iii) Why it is a long time 10 days?

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html

gc_grace_seconds    864000 [10 days]    The number of seconds after data is marked with a tombstone (deletion marker) before it is eligible for garbage-collection. Cassandra will not execute hints or batched mutations on a tombstoned record within its gc_grace_period. The default value allows a great deal of time for Cassandra to maximize consistency prior to deletion. For details about decreasing this value, see garbage collection below.

3) I read that performing compaction and repair using nodetool will delete the tombstone, How frequently we need to run this in background, What will be the consequence of it?

Comment: And future reference; do try and limit yourself to one question per post.  One with a follow-up is ok, but five is definitely pushing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. This means that your query returned 76 "live" or non-deleted/non-obsoleted rows of data, and that it had to sift through 1324 tombstones (deletion markers) to accomplish that.
2. In the world of distributed databases, deletes are hard.  After all, if you delete a piece of data from one node, and you expect that deletion to happen on all of your nodes, how would you know if it worked?  Quite literally, how do you replicate *nothing*?  Tombstones (delete markers) are the answer to that question.

   i. The data is gone (obsoleted, rather).  The tombstone(s) will remain for `gc_grace_seconds`.

   ii. The "consequence" is that you'll have to put up with those tombstone warning messages for that duration, or find a way to run your query without having to scan over the tombstones.

   iii. The idea behind the 10 days, is that if the tombstones are collected too early, that your deleted data will "ghost" its way back up to some nodes.  10 days gives you enough time to run a weekly repair, which ensures your tombstones are properly replicated before removal.
3. Compaction removes tombstones.  Repair replicates them.  You should run repair once per week.  While you *can* run compaction on-demand, ***don't***.  Cassandra has its own thresholds (based on number and size of SSTable files) to figure out when to run compaction, and it's best not to get in its way.  If you do, you'll be manually running compaction from there on out, as you'll probably never reach the compaction conditions organically.

The consequences, are that both repair and compaction take compute resources, and can reduce a node's ability to serve requests.  But they need to happen.  You *want* them to happen.  If compaction doesn't run, your SSTable files will grow in number and size; eventually causing rows to exist over multiple files, and queries for them will get slow.  If repair doesn't run, your data is at risk of not being in-sync.

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644528/tombstone-vs-nodetool-and-repair