# Tombstone vs nodetool and repair

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I inserted 10K entries in a table in Cassandra which has the TTL of 1 minute under the single partition.

After the successful insert, I tried to read all the data from a single partition but it throws an error like below,

```
WARN  [ReadStage-2] 2018-04-04 11:39:44,833 ReadCommand.java:533 - Read 0 live rows and 100001 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM qcs.job LIMIT 100 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
DEBUG [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-04-04 11:39:44,834 ReadCallback.java:132 - Failed; received 0 of 1 responses
ERROR [ReadStage-2] 2018-04-04 11:39:44,836 StorageProxy.java:1906 - Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM qcs.job LIMIT 100' (last scanned row partion key was ((job), 2018-04-04 11:19+0530, 1, jobType1522820944168, jobId1522820944168)); query aborted
```

I understand tombstone is an marking in the sstable not the actual delete.

So I performed the **compaction** and **repair** using **nodetool**

Even after that when I read the data from the table, It throws the same error in log file.

1) How to handle this scenario?

2) Could some explain why this scenario happened and Why not the compaction and repair didn't solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tombstones are really deleted after period specified by `gc_grace_seconds` setting of the table (it's 10 days by default).  This is done to make sure that any node that was down at time of deletion will pickup these changes after recover.  Here are the blog posts that discuss this in great details: [from thelastpickle (recommended)](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html), [1](https://opencredo.com/cassandra-tombstones-common-issues/), [2](https://www.beyondthelines.net/databases/cassandra-tombstones/), and [DSE documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDeletes.html) or [Cassandra documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/compaction.html?highlight=gc_grace_seconds).

You can set the `gc_grace_seconds` option on the individual table to lower value to remove deleted data faster, but this should be done only for tables with TTLed data.  You may also need to tweak `tombstone_threshold` & `tombstone_compaction_interval` table options to perform compactions faster.  See [this document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateTable.html) or [this document](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/compaction.html) for description of these options.

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878072/distributed-logs-in-cassandra

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385262/cassandra-commit-log-size

Comment: I tried to google it, got a very few info on this :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385262/cassandra-commit-log-size so could you give some light on this

Comment: please check this  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462617/native-transport-request-in-cassandra

Answer (score 0):

New cassandra support .

```
$ ./nodetool garbagecollect
```

After this command "Transfer memory to disk, before restart"

```
$ ./nodetool drain    # "This closes connection after that, clients can not access. "
```

Shutdown cassandra and restart again.   "You should restart after drain. "

** You do not need to drain, ! but, depends on situation.! These are extra informations.

Comment: You do not need to shutdown but best is that you should drain and restart it.

Comment: brrrrr - the recommendation to restart node is very bad. You shouldn't need it.

Comment: this depends on  situation. ! most cases  not GOOD. so you do not need to restart, A user should now what is the mean of the DRAIN command.  if you do not know the drain command, do not use it.