# Issues in growing commit logs

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a machine the commit logs keeps increasing upto 7.8 GB and still growing, I checked a property `commitlog_total_space_in_mb: 8192` which is commented in cassandra.yaml. I suspect it has to be the default.

1) What is the problem in growing commit log size?
2) Is it says my memtable treshold is not reached?

EDITED :

memtable_cleanup_threshold = 1/(memtable_flush_writers + 1) * (memtable_offheap_space_in_mb + memtable_heap_space_in_mb)

where recommended values are,

```
memtable_flush_writers -  Smaller of number of disks or number of cores with a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 8, so in our case it is '8'

memtable_offheap_space_in_mb - 1/4 of the heap size, so in our case it is 2GB
memtable_heap_space_in_mb - 1/4 of the heap size, so in our case it is 2GB
```

so calculation will be,

```
 memtable_cleanup_threshold = 1/(8 + 1) * 4096
 memtable_cleanup_threshold = 455MB
```

Why does it didn't flush reaching to 455 MB and remove the commit log?

Comment: The commitlog can be larger then your memtable space. Is 8gb of disk a problem? Why are you tuning it?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Is this correct 'I have currently 7.8 GB of commit log, so does it mean that the 7.8 gb of mem table data is available in memory currently' ? Because as per my knowledge, Once the Mem table is flushed into SSTable, commit log needs to be deleted

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I understand commit log is the combination of multiple memtables so when will the commit logs be removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, 8192MB (or 1/4 of log file disk space, whichever is smaller -- could apply if you have a smaller server) is the default. Source: [Cassandra documentation on commitlog_total_space_in_mb](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html?highlight=commitlog_total_space_in_mb#commitlog-total-space-in-mb).

To answer your questions:

(1) If the commitlog files continue to grow, you can run out of disk space.

(2) The configured threshold has not yet been met.

Edited after your additional questions to add:

Commitlogs aren't deleted when memtables are flushed.

Note the file size is preallocated based on your configuration size -- I think you already figured that out, but noting that here if anyone else tries to observe the file size via `ls` or similar.

If you `nodetool drain` or restart, they will be cleared. Otherwise, they will continue to grow to the max size and rotate around.

Here is a test to see what happens if you force a flush:

```
nodetool tablestats keyspace.table | grep "Memtable data size"
Memtable data size: 1292049

cat /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-A.log | wc -l
10418

cat /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-B.log | wc -l
0

nodetool flush

nodetool tablestats keyspace.table | grep "Memtable data size"
Memtable data size: 0

cat /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-A.log | wc -l
10419

cat /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-B.log | wc -l
0

nodetool drain

nodetool tablestats keyspace.table | grep "Memtable data size"
Memtable data size: 0

cat /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-A.log | wc -l
no such file

cat /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-B.log | wc -l
0
```

You see similar results if it flushes automatically based on memtable configuration. Throughout the following observed flushes, the commitlog was not purged either:

[image: Screenshot of Grafana graph of memtable size]

Comment: please check the EDIT section in question Thanks